# Create an app for apple watc without xcode

Tags: apple-watch

A few days ago, I get an apple watch series 2 from my friend. But now, I want to create my own app for my apple watch (just for me). I don‘t have a mac so I don‘t have xcode. Is there a way to create one without xcode? On my iphone I use a website and add it to my homescreen, so it looks with the right manifest like a real app. Is somehing like that maybe also possible with the apple watch?

Answer (score 0):

I think you must need a Mac to create the application for iPhone or apple watch

You can take a look on this website.
https://learnappmaking.com/xcode-for-windows-how-to/

Comment: Ok, the apple watch can‘t display html files, can they?